# NodeJS / Express function only invoked one time in Google Cloud functions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, timeout

I'm creating a google cloud function that sends a daily email to users but the function is only invoked first time after deployment and then always fails with timeout even after 300 seconds (In general it takes 10 - 15 seconds to execute).

The function is doing DB finds, for loops and if conditions, so I think it's a problem of request / response from the app so it's prevent future invokation. Can you please help me modify the code below.

```
app.get('/emails', function(req, res){
    var books = [];
    Book.find({}, (err, res) => {
       if (err) {
           return err;
       }
       books = res;
   }).catch(err => console.log(err))
   User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }

    const uniques = users.filter(
      (v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => t.ID === v.ID) === i
    );

    for(var i =0; i < uniques.length; i++) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < books.length; j++) {
        if (books[j].UserID === uniques[i].ID && books[j].State === "OK") {
          count += 1;
        }
      }
      var EmailPayload = {
          // nodemailer object here
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      Email.sendEmailIndex(EmailPayload);
    }
    } 
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
  });
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you added `console.log` statements and included the logs of the execution to know where stops the execution.

Comment: How is the function triggered exactly?

Comment: it's triggered by HTTP invokation GET /cloud/emails, the first time after deployment is invoked then the logs always says timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is being invoked by GET /emails which expects a response. Without a response, the function will keep running until it times out because Google doesn't know it finished.

To fix this, conclude with a basic 200 after the script is done. It's also sensible to respond in case of failure to cover all cases and make sure there's always a response sent back.

```js
app.get('/emails', function(req, res) {
    var books = [];
    Book.find({}, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        books = res;

        return User.find({}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }

            const uniques = users.filter(
                (v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => t.ID === v.ID) === i
            );

            for (var i = 0; i < uniques.length; i++) {
                var count = 0;
                for (var j = 0; j < books.length; j++) {
                    if (books[j].UserID === uniques[i].ID && books[j].State === "OK") {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
                var EmailPayload = {
                    // nodemailer object here
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    Email.sendEmailIndex(EmailPayload);
                }
            }

            // Send a response to conclude function execution
            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'Emails sent'
            });
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);

        // Send a response to conclude function execution
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Failed to send emails',
            error: err
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi, it directly sends {"message":"Emails sent"} when I invoke the GET , I tried to add some time before the message : 

  res.setTimeout(15000, function(){
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Emails sent' });
  })

It waits for 15 seconds but does not send emails.

Comment: I had to put all code from User.find() inside the Book.find() result then. It works now !

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense! The tricky part of working with promises :). I've updated the answer to reflect what you did. Because we put User.find() inside Book.find(), we can also get rid of the .catch() clause of User.find(). We return the result of User.find() which is going to go in the last .catch clause. I recommend learning async/await so you're able to write much simpler and easier to understand promises